# Underline in a text with red color in CSS

Tags: css

I want to write an underline with font color red.

I Tried like this

```
 <u> <li style="COLOR:red"><a href="/jobs.aspx/"> Internal Job Openings </a></li></u>
```

But the content is hiding. How to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `<u>` tag.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot wrap an LI with a U-tag.

Comment: what is it you want in red: the text, the underline, both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the default style for `a` as well:

```
<ul>
    <li style="color:red"><a style="color:red" href="#">foo</a></li>
</ul>
```

see the [fiddle....](http://jsfiddle.net/76e4k/)

Comment: `style="color:red"` if u ignore from li also it will work +1 cool

Comment: If you leave the color off the LI, your bullet won't be red.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your HTML is invalid. You cannot enclose a `<li>` inside a `<u>` tag. And remove the `<u>` tag as it is deprecated. Use the CSS's `color` and `text-decoration` rules to achieve your result.

Change it to this way:

```
<li style="COLOR:red; text-decoration: underline;">
    <a href="/jobs.aspx/"> Internal Job Openings </a>
</li>
```

If you just need it for the link, then give the style to the link.

```
<li style="COLOR:red;">
    <a style="text-decoration: underline;" href="/jobs.aspx/"> Internal Job Openings </a>
</li>
```

Comment: `text-decoration: underline` is it required ?? `a`tag itself have by its birth :)

Comment: What if it has a rule like `a {text-decoration: none;}`

Comment: <li style="COLOR:red; text-decoration: underline;"> <a href="/jobs.aspx/" style="COLOR:red;> Internal Job Openings </a> </li>    The color is coming BLUE...I want it RED

Comment: OKay, try this: `<li style="COLOR:red; text-decoration: underline;"> <a href="/jobs.aspx/" style="COLOR:red; text-underline: none;"> Internal Job Openings </a> </li>`